# Run different code for a class that has either an object or an array of objects as a member

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I have a method that takes an object as parameter

```
void fun(const Obj& obj)
```

`Obj` can be defined in two different ways:

```
struct Obj
{
   Type x;
};
```

and

```
struct Obj
{
   Type x[42];
};
```

I cannot modify the definitions of `Obj` (i.e. I can't rename the classes). Also, I can't modify the signature of `fun` and I'd rather not use preprocessor directives inside of `fun`. Is there a way to use metaprogramming to make this compile and work regardless of which definition of `Obj` is included:

```
void fun(const Obj& obj)
{
   impl(obj); // executes some code if obj.x is an object
              // executes some other code if obj.x is an array 
}
```

? Is there a way to do it without C++11 features?

Comment: Sorry, I've overseen the _without C++11 features_ restriction. Anyway, it could be a good idea to check the anatomies of the [`std::is_array()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_array) static check, to see how it could be implemented for c++03 standards (I'm pretty sure it should be possible).

Answer (score 2):

You could pick a specialization of a template based on `decltype(obj.x)`:

```
template<typename T>
void impl(const Obj&);

template<> 
void impl<Type>(const Obj&) {}

template<>
void imp<Type[42]>(const Obj&) {}


void fun(const Obj& obj)
{
   impl<decltype(obj.x)>(obj);
}
```

Possible C++03 way is a member detector trait class that checks for existence of `Type Obj::x`. This time, template parameter of `impl` would be `bool` so you can simply pass the result of the check:

```
template<typename C>
struct has_Type_x {
    template<typename U, U>
    struct Check;

    typedef char(&yes)[1];
    typedef char(&no)[2];

    template<typename> static no test(...);
    template<typename U> static yes test(Check<Type U::*, &U::x>*);

    static const bool value = sizeof(test<C>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};

template<bool> void impl(const Obj&);

template<>
void impl<true>(const Obj&) {}

template<>
void impl<false>(const Obj&) {
    std::cout << "arr";
}

void fun(const Obj& obj)
{
   impl< has_int_x<Obj>::value >(obj);
}
```

Comment: Say I can't use C++11?

Comment: That'll take some more typing. Brb :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by a second call to an implementation function `fun_impl` that also takes `obj.x` as an argument. This function specializes to scalars or arrays by two overloads, the latter accepting a reference to an array, so maintaining the array size as well:

```
template <typename Obj, typename T>
void fun_impl(const Obj& obj, const T& x) {}

template <typename Obj, typename T, size_t N>
void fun_impl(const Obj& obj, const T (&x)[N]) {}

template <typename Obj>
void fun(const Obj& obj)
{
   fun_impl(obj, obj.x);
}
```

This works in C++03 and does not require any traits features or SFINAE. See also [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c14f0e245a8607b7), where the remaining parts use C++11 for convenience.

If `obj` only contains `x`, you can drop it as an argument from `fun_impl`. I left it here for the more general case where `obj` might have other members as well.

Note that `fun` itself is given as a template here; I guess this is what you need to do anyway since you are dealing with different definitions of `Obj`.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution doesn't fit the requirements because OP "can't modify the signature of fun".

Comment: @AlexAntonov My solution refers to specializing for scalars or arrays. Adding a template argument to `fun` is just another suggestion. These two are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use function overloading. You don't need metaprogramming/templates in your case:

```
void fun(const Obj& obj)
{
   impl(obj.x);
}

void impl(const Type& x){...}
void impl(Type x[]){...}
```

If `Obj::x` is declared as `Type x` then the first `impl()` version will be called. And similarly in another case the second `impl()` version will be called.